# How to Delete the last element in a linked list in C?

Tags: c, list, dynamic, linked-list, allocation

I don't know how to delete the first and last element in a linked list in c. Below is my program, that uses a linked list. I have no idea how to actually delete the last element but I am able to find it. the element consists of an integer and the next pointer. if someone could please help me, it would be much appreciated.

```
struct ListNode{
    int value;
    struct ListNode *next;
};
typedef struct ListNode Link;

void deleteLast(Link *);
void printList(Link *);
void deleteFirst(Link *);

int main(){
    Link *myList;
 Link *curr, *newlink;
 int i;
    curr = myList;
    for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){

            newlink = (Link*) malloc(1*sizeof(Link));
            newlink->value = i*i;
            curr->next = newlink;
            curr = newlink;
    }

    curr->next = NULL;
    curr = myList->next;
    deleteFirst(curr);
    printList(curr);
    printf("\n");
}
void deleteLast(Link *head)
{
    Link *curr;
    curr = head->next;
    while (curr->next!=NULL)
    {
        curr = curr->next;
    }
     free(curr->next);

    curr->next = NULL;

}
void printList(Link *head){
    Link *curr;
    curr = head->next;

    printf("[");
    if(curr!=NULL){
        printf("%d",curr->value);
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    while(curr != NULL){
        printf(", %d", curr->value);
        curr = curr->next;
    }
    printf("]\n");

}
void deleteFirst(Link *head){
    Link *curr;
    curr = head->next;
    free(curr->value);
    free(curr->next);
    printf("%d\t",curr->value);
}
```

Nothing I try works, please can you help me.

Comment: your delete first also is wrong, you must get i Link** and not a link*

Comment: I started in on an answer but realized that the code above is very badly broken long before attempting to *remove* any list elements.  In particular `myList` is never initialized, but `curr` is set to whatever garbage value it may have; then `curr->next` is written-to, even though `curr` is a copy of whatever trash value might have been in `myList` initially.  Once you fix that, see existing questions like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906636/deleting-first-and-last-element-of-a-linked-list-in-c?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have many errors in your code.

- When you create your list:

  - You don't have to cast the return value of malloc
  - You are doing `curr->next = newlink;` where curr = myList with initialized value. You can change your loop to

> ```
>   Link *myList = NULL;
>   Link *curr, *newlink;
>   int i;
>
>   curr = myList;
>   for(i = 0; i < 10; i++){
>
>     newlink = malloc(1*sizeof(Link));
>     newlink->value = i*i;
>     if (curr != NULL)
>       curr->next = newlink;
>     else
>       myList = newlink;
>     curr = newlink;
>   }
> ```

- When you remove the last element you are going to far, that's why it's not working

> ```
>   Link  *curr;
>
>   curr = head->next;   
>   while (curr->next != NULL) {
>     head = curr;
>     curr = curr->next;
>   }
>
>   free(head->next);
>   head->next = NULL;
> ```

- When you want to remove the first element of your list

  - You don't have to free the field value since you have not allocated it with malloc
  - Even if you remove the first element of your list, you are not changing the value of the begining of your list in the main. It's why you must take as a param a `Link**`

> ```
> void deleteFirst(Link **head){
>   Link *curr;
>
>   curr = (*head)->next;
>   free(*head);
>   *head = curr;
> }
> ```

And you can call this function from the main by giving the address of the beginning of your list:

```
  deleteFirst(&myList);
  deleteLast(myList);
  printList(myList);
```

of course in all your functions you must check if you have at least some values in the list and not an empty pointer `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct node Node;
struct node{
    int element;
    Node *next;
};

Node* head = NULL;

bool put(int data)
{
    bool retVal = false;

    Node* temp;

    do
    {
        if (head == NULL)
        {
            head = malloc(sizeof(Node));

            if (head)
            {
                printf("New head created\n");
                head->element = data;
                head->next = NULL;
                printf("Element %d stored\n", data);

                retVal = true;
                break;
            }           
            else
            {           
                printf("Could not create new head\n");
                break;
            }   
        }

        temp = head;
        while (temp->next != NULL)
        {
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        temp->next = malloc(sizeof(Node));
        temp->next->element = data;
        temp->next->next = NULL;

        printf("Element %d stored\n", data);

        retVal = true;
        break;

    } while(1);

    return retVal;
}



bool get(int *pData)
{
    bool retVal = false;
    Node* temp;

    if (head != NULL)
    {
        retVal = true;
        Node *prevNode = head;

        temp = prevNode;
        while (temp->next)
        {
            prevNode = temp;
            temp = temp->next;
        }

        *pData = temp->element;
        printf("Element %d retrieved\n", *pData);

        free(temp);
        printf("Node freed\n");

        if (temp == head)
        {
            head = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
            prevNode->next = NULL;
        }   
    }

    return retVal;
}


int main(void)
{
    int retrievedNum;
    int num;

    for (num = 0; num < 5; num++)
    {
        put(num);
    }

    printf("\n");

    for (num = 0; num < 6; num++)
    {
        get(&retrievedNum);
    }

    put(num);

    get(&retrievedNum);

    printf("Element retrieved: %d\n", retrievedNum);

    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code will work for deleting last element in linklist:**

```
void dellast()

{

r=head;

struct node* z;
do
{
    z=r;
    r=r->next;
    if(r->next==NULL)
    {
        z->next=NULL;
        free(r->next);
    }   
}while(z->next!=NULL);
}
```

**The Code works like this:**

> Keep the track of current node and its previous node.
>
> If current->next==NULL means it is the last node.
>
> So do previous->next=NULL and free the current node

Answer (score 0):

I've made my own (singly) LinkedList example in C, its proven to work:

```
#include  <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/********** GLOBALS *******************************/
#define OK 0
#define ERROR -1

/********** STRUCT AND TYPES DEFINTIONS ***********/
/* a node with key, data and reference to next node*/
typedef struct Node {
    int key;
    char string[1024];
    struct Node *next;  // pointer to next node
} Node;

/* the actual linked list: ref to first and last Node, size attribute */
typedef struct LinkedList {
    struct Node *first;
    struct Node *last;
    int size;
} LinkedList;

/********** FUNCTION HEADERS **********************/
LinkedList* init_list();
void insert_end(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]);
void insert_beginning(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]);
int remove_end(LinkedList *list);
int remove_beginning(LinkedList *list);
int print_list(LinkedList *list);
void free_list(LinkedList *list);
char * get_string(LinkedList *list, int key);

/*********** FUNCTION DEFINITIONS ***************/

/**
 * init_list Returns an appropriately (for an empty list) initialized struct List
 *
 * @return LinkedList *         ..ptr to the newly initialized list
 */
LinkedList * init_list() {
    printf("initializing list...\n");

    LinkedList *list = (LinkedList*) malloc(sizeof(LinkedList));

    list->first = NULL;
    list->last = NULL;
    list->size = 0;

    return list;
}

/**
 * Given a List, a key and a string adds a Node containing this
 * information at the end of the list
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *    ..ptr to LinkedList
 * @param key       int             .. key of the Node to be inserted
 * @param string    char[]          .. the string of the Node to be inserted
 */
void insert_end(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]) {
    printf("----------------------\n");

    list->size++;                    // increment size of list

    // intialize the new Node
    Node* newN = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newN->key = key;
    strcpy(newN->string, string);
    newN->next = NULL;

    Node* oldLast = list->last;      // get the old last
    oldLast->next = newN;          // make new Node the next Node for oldlast
    list->last = newN;              // set the new last  in the list

    printf("new Node(%p) at end: %d '%s' %p \n", newN, newN->key, newN->string,newN->next);
}

/**
 * Given a List, a key and a string adds a Node, containing
 * this information at the beginning of the list
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *    ..ptr to LinkedList
 * @param key       int             .. key of the Node to be inserted
 * @param string    char[]          .. the string of the Node to be inserted
 */
void insert_beginning(LinkedList *list, int key, char string[]) {
    printf("----------------------\n");

    list->size++;                    // increment size of list
    Node* oldFirst = list->first;    //get the old first node

    /* intialize the new Node */
    Node* newN = (Node*) malloc(sizeof(Node));
    newN->key = key;
    strcpy(newN->string, string);
    newN->next = oldFirst;

    list->first = newN;              // set the new first

    /* special case: if list size == 1, then this new one is also the last one */
    if (list->size == 1)
        list->last = newN;

    printf("new Node(%p) at beginning: %d '%s' %p \n", newN, newN->key,newN->string, newN->next);
}

/**
 * Removes the first Node from the list
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *        .. ptr to the List
 *
 * @return OK | ERROR
 */
int remove_beginning(LinkedList *list) {
    printf("----------------------\n");

    if (list->size <= 0)
        return ERROR;

    list->size--;

    Node * oldFirst = list->first;

    printf("delete Node(%p) at beginning: '%d' '%s' '%p' \n", oldFirst,oldFirst->key, oldFirst->string, oldFirst->next);

    free(list->first);          //free it
    list->first = oldFirst->next;
    oldFirst = NULL;

    return OK;
}

/**
 * Removes the last Node from the list.
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *        .. ptr to the List
 *
 * @return OK | ERROR
 */
int remove_end(LinkedList *list) {
    printf("----------------------\n");

    /* special case #1 */
    if (list->size <= 0)
        return ERROR;

    /* special case #2 */
    if (list->size == 1) {
        free(list->first);
        list->first = NULL;
        list->last = NULL;
        return OK;
    }

    printf("delete Node(%p) at end: '%d' '%s' '%p' \n", list->last,list->last->key, list->last->string, list->last->next);

    list->size--;           // decrement list size
    Node * startNode = list->first;

    /* find the new last node (the one before the old last one); list->size >= 2 at this point!*/
    Node * newLast = startNode;
    while (newLast->next->next != NULL) {
        newLast = newLast->next;
    }

    free(newLast->next);    //free it
    newLast->next = NULL;   //set to NULL to denote new end of list
    list->last = newLast;   // set the new list->last

    return OK;
}

/**
 * Given a List prints all key/string pairs contained in the list to
 * the screen
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *        .. ptr to the List
 *
 * @return  OK | ERROR
 */
int print_list(LinkedList *list) {

    printf("----------------------\n");

    if (list->size <= 0)
        return ERROR;

    printf("List.size = %d \n", list->size);

    Node *startN = list->first;  //get first

    /* iterate through list and print contents */
    do {
        printf("Node#%d.string = '%s', .next = '%p' \n", startN->key,startN->string, startN->next);
        startN = startN->next;
    } while (startN != NULL);

    return OK;
}

/**
 * Given a List, frees all memory associated with this list.
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *        ..ptr to the list
 */
void free_list(LinkedList *list) {
    printf("----------------------\n");
    printf("freeing list...\n");

    if (list != NULL && list->size > 0) {
        Node * startN = list->first;
        Node * temp = list->first;

        do {
            free(temp);
            startN = startN->next;
            temp = startN;
        } while (startN != NULL);

        free(list);
    }
}

/**
 * Given a List and a key, iterates through the whole List and returns
 * the string of the first node which contains the key
 *
 * @param list      LinkedList *        ..ptr to the list
 * @param key       int                 .. the key of the Node to get the String from
 *
 * @return OK | ERROR
 */
char * get_string(LinkedList *list, int key) {
    printf("----------------------\n");

    Node *startN = list->first;  //get first

    /* iterate through list and find Node where node->key == key */
    while (startN->next != NULL) {
        if (startN->key == key)
            return startN->string;
        else
            startN = startN->next;
    }

    return NULL;
}

/*************** MAIN **************/
int main(void) {

    LinkedList *list = init_list();

    insert_beginning(list, 1, "im the first");
    insert_end(list, 2, "im the second");
    insert_end(list, 3, "im the third");
    insert_end(list, 4, "forth here");

    print_list(list);
    remove_end(list);
    print_list(list);
    remove_beginning(list);
    print_list(list);
    remove_end(list);
    print_list(list);
    printf("string at node with key %d = '%s' \n",2,get_string(list, 2));
    free_list(list);

    return OK;
}
```

Hope this implementation example helps.